# How to store multiple rows of a table in different variables using the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure in SQL Server. In it, I need to multiply different rows of a table and I need to store the results in different variables.

For example, let's suppose I have this table:

```
   | Column A | Column B | Column C |
   | -------- | -------- |----------| 
   | Cell 1   | Cell 2   | Cell 3   |
   | Cell 4   | Cell 5   | Cell 6   |
   | Cell 7   | Cell 8   | Cell 9   |
```

The calculation will look like this

```
  var1 = (Cell1 * Cell8) - Cell2/109
  var2 = (Cell5 * Cell7) - Cell1
  var3 = (Cell2 * Cell3) - Cell9 * Cell3
```

Helpful, if anyone has idea how a solution for this problem can be implemented.

**Edit: More Clarification added.**

I need to do a complex tax calculation which is currently done manually via excel. Below is how the tax table looks like and this table will be used for the calculation of tax.

```
   | N (lower range) | N (Higher Range) | Rate |
   | ----------------| ---------------- |------| 
   |       0         |  20000           |  0   |
   |     20001       |  80000           | .30  |
   |     80001       |  above           | .45  |
```

Here N Stands for Salary

The calculation to calculate the tax is as follows:

```
If NetSalary < 20000 then
tax=0
If NetSalary > 20001 and NetSalary < 80000 then
tax= ( NetSalary*26 - 20000 * .30 ) / 26
If NetSalary > 80001 
tax = ( NetSalary*26 - ( ( 20000 * .45 ) + ( (80000 -20000) * ( .45 - .30) ) ) ) /26
```

Here 26 is a constant value. All other numerical values are populated from the tax table. Below sample shows how this calculation looks in excel.

```
   |   NL     |    NH    | Rate    |
   | -------- | -------- |---------| 
   |   NL1    |    NH1   | Rate1   |
   |   NL2    |    NH2   | Rate2   |
   |   NL3    |    NH3   | Rate3   |



 If NetSalary < NH1 then
    tax=0
    If NetSalary > NL2 and NetSalary < NH2 then
    tax= ( NetSalary*26 - NH1 * Rate2 ) / 26
    If NetSalary > 80001 
    tax = ( NetSalary*26 - ( ( NH1 * Rate3 ) + ( (NH2 - NH1) * ( Rate3 - Rate2) ) ) ) /26
```

As it is evident that this is not straightforward tax calculation. It needs input from the previous cells as well. My idea is to put the calculation which is taking input from the tax table into a variable and then subtract it from NetSalary*26.

I need to understand if this can be implemented via the stored proc.

Comment: Store them in different variables... to then do what? If you have an unknown number of rows, you should put them in a table variable (but I bet there's a way to do what you want without using variables at all).

Comment: i'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but please stop thinking DBMS as spreadsheet.

Comment: Please add some more illustrative data and show the desired results; this has the ring of an XYProblem.

Comment: I think it's better to move this back to Excel

Comment: Well it coul dbe done if the exact logic could be defined...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This process needs to be automated and hence require stored proc.

Comment: Unfortunately our SQL "gurus" are not familiar with tax calculations, hence they spat a dummy a closed your question. Having said that, you are over complicating this (and your logic looks worong)! First of all: calculate "accumulated" tax amount for each bracket and store it in its own column e.g. accumulated tax for 2001 bracket is 0 and for 80001 bracket would be 18000. Then you have a simple query: `SELECT accumulated + (salary - NL) * Rate FROM x WHERE salary BETWEEN NL AND NH`

Comment: @Alex thanks for response. This is exactly what I am trying to do. However, as you can see the calculation for accumulated amount changes as the salary band changes and it takes input from multiple rows. Wanted to understand if this is something which can achieved via SQL?

Comment: I think you have made a mistake extrapolating Excel tax calculations. This `tax= ( NetSalary*26 - 20000 * .30 ) / 26` is clearly missing parentheses, should be: `tax= (( NetSalary*26 - 20000 ) * .30 ) / 26`. `If NetSalary > 80001 ` logic is too "wild" to comment on. Your logic should be similar to what I have described in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I tested this approach and this is what I was expecting. You saved my day. Thanks a lot. May be you can post it as an answer if you like and I can accept it. Others will get benefitted as well.

Comment: Glad to help :)    P.S. I did upvote your question but I can only do it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tax tier/bracket calculation logic I suggest you do the following:

Calculate "accumulated" tax amount for each bracket and store it in its own column. This amount is made up of tax amounts for all preceding tiers.

| NL (lower range) | NH (Higher Range) | Rate | Accumulated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20000 | 0 | 0 |
| 20001 | 80000 | .30 | 0 |
| 80001 | above | .45 | 1800 |

I suggest using a very large number as the `NH` value for the top tier instead of "above" string e.g. 1000000000 (1 billion)

Then all you would need to calculate tax is a simple query

```
SELECT ((salary - NL) * Rate ) + Accumulated AS TaxAmount
FROM x
WHERE salary BETWEEN NL AND NH
```